# c# thread infinite loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, join

I am trying to run two set of threads using `AutoResetEvent` to coordinate with each other;
After the first set (customer) is done, I used `thread.join()` to make sure all threads in the first set is done, the set the flag to stop the second thread.  However, the `thread.join()` never complete and the debugger lost its track in between.  The flag was never set so it keeps running.
Can someone please see what goes wrong here?  Thanks!

```
private static AutoResetEvent tellerFree = new AutoResetEvent(true);
private volatile static bool doneflag = true;
public static void runMultTeller()
{

    List<Thread> custThreads = new List<Thread>();
    List<Thread> tellThreads = new List<Thread>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
    {
        Thread td = new Thread(getTeller);
        td.Name = Convert.ToString(i);
        custThreads.Add(td);
        td.Start();
    }

    for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
    {
        Thread tt = new Thread(doTelling);
        tt.Name = Convert.ToString(j);
        custThreads.Add(tt);
        tt.Start();
    }

    foreach (Thread tc in custThreads)
    {
        if (tc.IsAlive)
        {
            tc.Join();
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Customer are done");

    doneflag = false;

    foreach (Thread t2 in tellThreads)
    {
        t2.Join();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Teller are done");

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}

static public void doTelling()
{
    string name = Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
    while (doneflag)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("teller#{0} serving", name);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine("teller#{0} done", name);
        tellerFree.Set();
    }
}

static public void getTeller()
{
    string name = Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
    Console.WriteLine("customer#{0} Enter", name);
    tellerFree.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine("customer#{0} Leave", name);

}
```

Comment: Don't you need a semaphore for this?

Comment: If you're working on a producer/consumer relationship between these threads, I suggest reading through [this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/deadlocks.shtml). I'm not sure if this was intentional on your part, but with the way you have things set up now there is a chance that all 50 consuming threads could be released by one producing thread. I would imagine you want each item produced by a thread to be consumed by exactly 1 consuming thread. If not, then I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.  I wasn't try to do that in this sample.  Maybe next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change:

```
custThreads.Add(tt);
```

in the second 'for' loop to:

```
tellThreads.Add(tt);
```

Otherwise your Join() call will wait forever for the doTelling() threads to finish which will never happen because the doneFlag will be never set.

Comment: I totally missed that. Well spotted!

Comment: Stupid me!  That's what happen when you copy and paste.  I spot the additional threads when I debugged the code.  But the debugger then disappeared (I guess waiting for unfinished threads to join) so I thought something else went wrong.  Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

Marking a boolean as `volatile` does not ensure that other threads observe that change immediately. It only ensures that *if* other threads observe the change, they will afterwards also observe all other writes that were done by the thread that wrote the volatile variable before writing it.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx for more information:

> Actually, that last bit is a lie. The true semantics of volatile reads and writes are considerably more complex than I've outlined here; in fact they do not actually guarantee that every processor stops what it is doing and updates caches to/from main memory. Rather, they provide weaker guarantees about how memory accesses before and after reads and writes may be observed to be ordered with respect to each other. Certain operations such as creating a new thread, entering a lock, or using one of the Interlocked family of methods introduce stronger guarantees about observation of ordering. If you want more details, read sections 3.10 and 10.5.3 of the C# 4.0 specification.
>
> Frankly, I discourage you from ever making a volatile field. Volatile fields are a sign that you are doing something downright crazy: you're attempting to read and write the same value on two different threads without putting a lock in place. Locks guarantee that memory read or modified inside the lock is observed to be consistent, locks guarantee that only one thread accesses a given hunk of memory at a time, and so on.

UPDATE:
The code in the question has a bigger problem than just using `volatile`, as noticed by Oleg Mikhaylov. After correcting that problem, the program would probably work most of the time. Nevertheless, I leave this answer here, because the use of `volatile` is a second problem indeed.

I also heavily recommend that you read the book [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/threading.pdf) by Joseph Albahari.

Comment: @EdS. No it doesn't. The statement "This ensures that the most up-to-date value is present in the field at all times." is incorrect.

Comment: Wow, if that's true it is one hell of an oversight.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I first thought the doneflag was the issue then added volatile.  It just a simple way to set a global variable for all threads but definitely not a good practice.

Comment: I suppose I didn't know because I have never used it in C#, preferring `InterlockedExchange`.  I can find other places with the same issue as the first link I gave (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686355(v=vs.85).aspx).  I have noticed that the C# documentation has a habit of glossing over important details.